# Different ways of rendering collection of records rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to render a collection of elements using partials in rails. I found 3 approaches that work, but not all for the same html document.
These are the approaches that I found working, but I don t understand why some work in some files and some dont.

```
<%= j render @event_messages %>

<%= render @event_messages%>

<%= render partial: 'event_message', collection: @event_messages%>
```

Let's say I have the html file index.html.erb and the partial _event_message.html.erb. Now I'll go over the 3 approaches:

`<%= render partial: 'event_message', collection: @event_messages%>` this line works perfectly in this case and the partial gets rendered as many times as required.

`<%= render @event_messages%>` throws the missing template error, but in other .html.erb files I can use it to render partials with no problems.

`<%= j render @event_messages %>` works in a .js.erb file, but what does the 'j' stand for? I'm using this approach with an ajax callback and for some cases it works, but for others I get the missing template error.

```
Missing partial event_messages/_event_message with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

I tried my best to describe the issue. If you need more information, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= j render @event_messages %>
```

`j` is an alias for [`escape_javascript`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper/escape_javascript) method.

This line works, well because it works...as intended

```
<%= render partial: 'event_message', collection: @event_messages%>
```

This one however will only work if the partial is within the `event_messages` sub folder, because it looks for the partial in `app/views/event_messages/_event_message.html.erb` and not in the current folder. So move your partial to the correct location and it will work.

```
<%= render @event_messages%>
```

Comment: Thank you. By adding `j` in front of `render partial: 'event_message', collection: @event_messages` solved the .js.erb missing template. The template is in the right folder though, no idea why `<%= render @event_messages%>` doesn't work.

Comment: Exactly the missing template one

Comment: And you do have a partial at that location `app/views/event_messages/_event_message.html.erb`?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now. My controller in which I use the show action is called 'events', and I have a partial called '_event.html.erb' and one '_event_message.html.erb'. And they are both located in `app/views/events`. And the one that is working is <%= render @events%>, so I assumed it would work with `<%= render @event_messages%>` too.

Comment: Ahh, I see, it has to be in `app/views/event_messages/_event_message.html.erb` for this shorthand form of render to work